# In reversing an integer , I am using two duplicated while loops, is there any way to refactor those while loops and instead use one?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public int reverse(int x) { 
    byte TEN=10; 
    long rev=0;
    if(x<0) {
        while(x<0) {
            rev = TEN*rev+(x%10);
            x /= 10;
        }      
    } else {
        while(x>0) {
            rev = TEN*rev+(x%10);
            x /= 10;
        }
    }      
    if(rev>2147483647 || rev<-2147483648) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return (int) rev;
}
```

I am unable to remove the duplicated while loop, is this the only way , else anyone help me to achieve this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you increment/decrement `x` at all?

Comment: the loops are not duplicates. There condition is different. And without knowing what `I want mango`and `I want apple` are, we can't help you. If it's just 2 method calls, there is probably no need to refactor.

Comment: for now, the question basically is: help me refactor the code I hide

Comment: @MuratK. -- consider `x` is the given input.

Comment: the question of MuratK was probably: what do you do with `x` as it looks like an infinite loop?

Comment: wait I will post the full code.

Comment: take that int, transform to a StringBuilder , call reverse, parse as int

Comment: @Eugene :- what about negative values while reversing and parsing?  ex: -123, becomes 321- when we reverse that and throws exception when parsing to int.

Comment: Make it positive, then make it negative again when returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the original version of this question: since `x` is not modified in either of the original loops:

```
while (true) {
    I want mango;
    I want apple;
}
```

For the updated version:

```
public int reverse(int x) { 
    byte TEN = 10; 
    long rev = 0;
    if (x != 0) {
        int sign = x < 0 ? -1 : +1;
        do {
            rev = TEN * rev + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        } while (x * sign > 0);     
    }     
    if (rev > 2147483647 || rev < -2147483648) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return (int) rev;
}
```

(Challenge: there is a subtle reason why you need to turn the `while` into a `do ... while`.  See if you can figure it out.)

But in my mind there is no doubt that the original code is better.  For a start, it is a lot easier to understand, than this or similar rewrites.  (Duplication is NOT bad if it helps you understand what the code is doing.)

Comment: No comment .... :-)

Comment: I have updated full code , can you explain how while(true) satisfies in this scenario:-

Comment: @MohanMunisifreddy - I answered the question **as you wrote it**.

Comment: First of all Thanks @StephenC your solution helped me to analyse another way of solving this.

Comment: @StephenC - I think there is no need to check for condition first, because the code will run either of the way. Is this the subtle reason?

Comment: No ... that's not the reason.  Hint: for what 2 values of `int x` does `x == -x` ?

Comment: @StephenC: Sorry, I can't figure it out, but I am eagerly interested in finding this.

Comment: Answer: `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1` is less than zero.  So if you do that test at the start of the loop ....

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions are avoiding `x == 0` so you might be able to simplify by using `0` or absolute value with [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)):

```
while (x != 0) {
  I want mango;
  I want apple;
}
```

Comment: I assume `x` is decremented and incremented in each part, with this how would you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(x != 0) {
            I want mango;
            I want apple;
        }
```

But my guess is that you were aiming at something else (meaning there is some more interesting logic in the apples and mangos).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Predicate` with customized condition:

```
<T> T mangoApple(Predicate<T> loop, T x) {
    while (loop.test(x)) {
    // I want mango
    // I want apple
        // change x
    }
    return x;
}
```

For example:

```
if(x<0) {
    x = mangoApple(x -> x < 0, x);
} else {
    x = mangoApple(x -> x > 0, x);
}
```